# start_url with query ignored with Google Chrome in manifest

Tags: progressive-web-apps, manifest.json

I try to create a PWA. On my website I've added a `manifest.json`.

Everything works except for the property `start_url`.

**My manifest.json**

```
{
  "short_name": "Gestiaweb",
  "name": "Gestiaweb",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "/images/PWA_ICON_192x192.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "192x192"
    },
    {
      "src": "/images/PWA_ICON_512x512.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512"
    }
  ],
  "id": "/?source=pwa",
  "start_url": "/?source=pwa",
  "background_color": "#ff931e",
  "display": "fullscreen",
  "scope": "/",
  "theme_color": "#ff931e",
  "orientation": "portrait",
  "shortcuts": [],
  "description": "Solution de gestion web",
  "screenshots": []
}
```

I'd like to start my PWA using the param `source=pwa`.

But when I install the app, the query is not added.

Could you explain me the issue ?